# Why LIKE returns no rows selected in sql?

Tags: sql, select, sql-like

I have this issue that's been bugging me for an hour.

Table:

```
--------------------------------------------
NAME    |                       CHAR(10)   |
SURNAME |                       CHAR(10)   |
RANK    |                       VARCHAR2(5)|
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract the NAME and the SURNAME if the surname ends with letter `'n'`.

NOTES: `LIKE` doesn't work very well with char(10) so I converted that column to varchar2(10) , using :

```
ALTER TABLE students
MODIFY SURNAME VARCHAR2(10);
```

And I tried this:

```
SELECT NAME,SURNAME
FROM students
WHERE SURNAME LIKE '%n';
```

> Unfortunately it gives me : no rows selected.

I'm thinking my column has spaces after last character ..

Still I don't know how my condition should look like.

I even tried calling to_char() function , it gives me the same output.

Comment: show some sample data

Comment: What does the data look like? Do you have any surnames that end with the letter N?

Comment: I am wondering why a char(10) and not a varchar 2 for your names, but have you tried SURNAME LIKE '%n%';

Comment: are there any surnames that end with 'n' ?

Comment: What db are you using?

Comment: if you want to look for trailing spaces select surname from students where len(surname) <> datalength(surname)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have an issue with spaces in the data.

Try this:

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME
FROM students
WHERE rtrim(SURNAME) LIKE '%n'
```

Comment: Yes apparently I did. Still the data didn't have any spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a type casting on the column you mentioned so try.

Select name,surname 
from   students
where  rtrim(upper(surname)) like '%N';

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an alternative:    WHERE CHARINDEX('n',surname) > 0

Comment: charindex is not avaialable in all database systems and the OP did not specify his.